# style doesn't work on TextView as expected in Android

Tags: android, textview, styles

I have a TextView and this is the xml code for it

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sidelist_item_count"
            style="@style/HomeTextViewItemCount"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my Style

```
<style name="HomeTextViewItemCount">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/home_textview_count</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I want to make my `TextView` circular. This doesn't expand when there are 3 digit numbers entered. But if I remove the style attribute from the `TextView` and set `android:background="@drawable/home_textview_count"` in my text view and added rest of the attributes inside Style into my Text view. then it works as expected. Can I know why cannot we set the style and what's the mistake I have done?
Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Your code seems fine just check that , in which styles xml have you written , do u have separate styles file for v-19 / v-21 / v-23 api versions ? `Post the styles file name`. Mostly u are testing API versions which are not supported by the styles !

Comment: @SantanuSur I don't have separate style files

Comment: @SantanuSur And I am checking on API 28 semulator

Comment: @SantanuSur style file is styles.xml